# nested router going back to parent

Tags: ember.js

I have nested router setup something like this:

```
this.resource('companies', function() {
    this.resource('company', {path:':company_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('employees', {path:'employees/:company_id'});
    });
});
```

When I click link to company and then link to employee, it's fine. Unless I move to a different company (id) first, if I continue to click link to the same company again, it doesn't display the company.

So basicaly 1st I go to /companies, it lists the companies, each one will have two links, one to /companies/1, other to /companies/1/employees/1, if I move to /companies/1/employees/1, then back to /companies/1, it no longer renders unless I first go to /companies/2, then move to /companies/1 will appear. Then the process repeats if I'm on the same companies "id" path.

I have it setup so that the same outlet is used for company and employees, and everything works except this.

My two links I have setup in template for each item like this:

```
{{#link-to 'company' this}}View Details: {{name}}{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'employees' id}}Employees{{/link-to}}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is as I'm new to Ember.js and experimenting. Thanks for any response.

Comment: you already have the company id in  `/companies/1/employees` why do you need to repeat it again at the end?

Comment: Yes, you're right I tried to eliminate that, but I'm new to Ember. What I'm doing is passing the company ID as a URL parameter to get the employees under this company. In the EmployeesRoute, I'm accessing the params from the model callback, to the ajax call. ie: employees_url + '?company=' + params.company_id.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do with without passing in the id once more.

Comment: Also, not using any Ember "backend", I'm using ajax calls (atleast for now) based off the model callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `company.id` again to your nested route, because it is nested, that means the parent's model is already resolved, and you have access to it with `modelFor` inside your employees route:

```
this.resource('companies', function() {
    this.resource('company', {path:':company_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('employees');
    });
});

// routes/employees.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var company = this.modelFor('company');

    return Ember.$.getJSON(employees_url + '?company=' + company.get('id'));
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, this works and for some reason (since I don't quite understand the internals of Ember) it solves the issue I had. The only change I had to do was company.get('id') gave me an error, I had to use dot notation: company.id.

Comment: perhaps this is because I'm using the newest version of Ember?

Comment: not really, it really depends on what you are returning from your `model` hook in the company route.

Comment: ah, I see. So if I'm passing back {name:'foobar', id:'8'}, for this I need to use dot notation, and if I'm using a backend such as store (I assume), it would return an object I can call "get" method on? Thanks again, I really like Ember so far, have only been at it for a full day now.

Comment: Yes, when you use `ember-data` you get back a model, which ultimately extends `Ember.Object` but I am glad you got it working :)